# How i can color partly a ImageView

Tags: android, colors, android-imageview, android-calendar

I'm developing a calendar. I have a multicolumns listview and each cell of listview is composed by an image view.
My question is.... To create an event that start hour is for example 13.20 until 13.45, how i can color imageview in only this segment of time?

Anyone can give me an example?
I put an image that is an example of what i pretend.

[image]

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't loose your time with the `ImageView` because they won't do that. Start writing your own `View` subclass, it will save you time later on. Simply override the `onDraw` method and use the `Canvas` object to draw rectangles at the right place.

To make the view you need, I would have a grid view holding in each row a custom component responsible for rendering the corresponding agenda slot corresponding to the day (column) and the time range (row).

Comment: Yep - This is where I would go also. The only other potential option would be to have each calendar entry be its own view (and he would still have to implement the placement algorithm), where he can truly use the simple setBackground color case. I think that would be much more of a memory hog though!

Answer (score 0):

Just as another option (and I agree with MarvinLabs approach but want to throw this out there).

You could have a main ViewController that for each entry adds a UIView as a subview.  With that you could potentially more simply set the background color and border of each entry.  You would have to implement your placement algorithm.

I BELIEVE that MarvinLabs approach would result in a smaller footprint (memory wise) however, how much I dont know.  At least this is another option.

Further, as an explanation of why you probably DONT want to use an imageView is that an imageView inherently comes with a lot of code that is un-necessary to you, such as the image decoders, image display code, etc...  Since you arent actually using images, you dont need to incorporate this code (by default if you use imageView objects) into your binary.